# Динамически адаптивный шрифт html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, scss

я верстаю макет сайта и нашёл в Интрнете формулу по которой шрифт сам подстраивается под размер экрана. Вот она `font-size: calc(25px + (40 + 40 * 0.7) *(100vw - 320px) / 1170);` 25px - это минимально возможный шрифт. 1170 - ширина котейнера. Нету смысла обьяснять всю формулу. Кому интересно, гляньте это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJZP5QsrpXs. Суть вопроса: при измене шрифта `line-height` остаётся прежним. То есть при увеличенном шрифте текст наезжает на себя, а при уменьшении слишком большие отступы. У кого-то есть подобная формула для `line-height`.

Comment: Сделай на css медиа-запросы по основным брекпоинтам и пропиши font-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, у вас line-height задан жестко в единицах. Нужно сделать line-height:normal, тогда он будет меняться вслед за размером шрифта.

Comment: или задать его в относительных единицах, например, 1.2 или 120%

Comment: Да , ты прав на счёт этого.